# android layout button does not look as expected

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to create 2 buttons in horizontal layout which will contain icon on the top.

Layout:

```
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/button" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Button:

```
<item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="right"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_call"/>
</item>
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >

        <gradient 
            android:startColor="#FFEEC9A8"
            android:endColor="#90FFDAB9"
            android:angle="45"/>

        <padding 
            android:left="7dp"
            android:right="7dp"
            android:top="7dp"
            android:bottom="7dp"/>

        <corners android:radius="10dp"/>

        <stroke android:width="2px" android:color="#ff888888"/>

    </shape>
</item>
```

I expect it will look like on first picutre, however it looks like on second with a gray area around the icon. What is wrong?

[image]
[image]

After I added android:scaleType="fitXY" the buttons looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following attribute to your `ImageButton`'s XML...

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

So, you XML will be...

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/button"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/button"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

**Update:**

Anothr thing I will recommend you to use `android:background` instead of `android:src` as follows...

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/button"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

**Another way:**

if you want to using `ImageView` then you can do as below...

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/button" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/button" />
```

Comment: Thank you. The proper area in the button is bigger but still there is a gray around. Please see the new picture in the question.

Comment: @Jacob For that you use Image View

Comment: @ShabbirDhangot ImageView solve appearance problem. However will I be able to use onClick with ImageView? Cause I need a button.

Comment: @Jacob...yeah, youh can also set the `onClick()` to `ImageView`.

Answer (score 1):

Quiet simple it is.

No need to create layer list and all
Just use below code

```
<ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
   android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
   android:paddingLeft="20dip"
   android:paddingRight="20dip"/>
```

If you observe I have used some plain color for background and provided some icon as an image.

So use two different properties like `android:background` and `android:src`

And for Round corner background first create a drawable named round_bg.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
    <corners android:radius="10dip" />
</shape>
```

Now in our above code do following modification

```
android:background="@drawable/round_bg"
```

And you will be done. :)

Comment: How can I to round the corners with this way?

Comment: Edited answer for rounded corner

Answer (score 1):

Yes You can use On Click with Image View

This is for reference only

Also One Thing You create Button With [Nine patches](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/nine-patches.html) so that Your Image will streach In some Part and will be responsive

for example

[image]

This is Nine patche Image so only the content part will be streach every time. rest will be as it is.